# How to construct tuple types of class template based on template parameter pack of sizt_t... Ints?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, template-meta-programming

In the context of c++17, how to construct the following tuple types (how to implement TypeMaker)?

```
template <size_t M, size_t N>
class A {
  // ...
}

template <size_t M>
class B {
 // ...
}

template <size_t... Ints>
struct TypeMaker {
 // here is the question
 // using typeA = ...
 // using typeB = ...
}
```

typeA and typeB would be like this:

```
typename TypeMaker<3, 5, 2, 10>::typeA  
-----> std::tuple<A<3, 5>, A<5, 2>, A<2, 10>>

typename TypeMaker<3, 5, 2, 10>::typeB
-----> std::tuple<B<5>, B<2>, B<10>> // drop first int 3

// sizeof...(Ints) has to be larger than 1 to have valid typeB
```

I'm looking for a generic type generator, so the same code will work on different number, such as:

```
TypeMaker<1, 2>, TypeMaker<3, 5, 3>, TypeMaker<1, 3, 9, 3, 10, 88, 128> ....
```

I have a feeling this could be done recursively, but not sure how.

Comment: I assume [this](https://godbolt.org/z/vqMro4) isn't what you want? If not, can you clarify how the variadic part is meant to work?

Comment: Not I want. The number of Ints is not always equal to 4, can be any int  larger than 1. I want a generic implementation so I don’t need to write new code when using different number of int. For example: TypeMaker<1, 2>, TypeMaker<1, 2, 3>, ... should be generated from the same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <size_t... Ints>
struct TypeMaker {
private:
  using Numbers = std::tuple<std::integral_constant<size_t, Ints>...>;
  template <size_t N>
  static constexpr size_t Number = std::tuple_element_t<N, Numbers>::value;

  template <size_t... Indexes>
  static std::tuple<A<Number<Indexes>, Number<Indexes + 1>>...>
  MakeA(std::index_sequence<Indexes...>);

  template <size_t... Indexes>
  static std::tuple<B<Number<Indexes + 1>>...>
  MakeB(std::index_sequence<Indexes...>);

public:
  using typeA = decltype(MakeA(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ints)-1>()));
  using typeB = decltype(MakeB(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ints)-1>()));
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hYjas6)

Comment: exactly what I want, Thanks!